# `express.redirect` on GCP Cloud Function won't redirect using Google Chrome

Tags: express, redirect, google-cloud-functions

I've got an `express`-based function deployed as GCP Cloud Function.
I'd like to redirect to an external website in one of my routes. Consider my following code:

```js
apiRouter.use(
  "/docs/asyncapi",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const asyncapi = await createUnifiedApi("./src/schemas/asyncapi.yml");
    // digging into AsyncAPI Studio code, we can utilize query params
    // https://github.com/asyncapi/studio/blob/150b7ad148459715bb97138a9af98e8d39032889/src/services/navigation.service.ts#L71
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      readOnly: "true",
      base64: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(asyncapi)).toString("base64"),
    }).toString();
    res.redirect("https://studio.asyncapi.com/?" + params);
  }),
);
```

When testing via `functions-framework` and Google Chrome, everything works correctly.
When deploying, I'm getting `Found. Redirecting to ...` web-page where no redirection ever happens. See the following:

[image]

Going to Chrome DevTools, this is the response I'm getting when the redirection works:

[image]

And this is when it doesn't:

[image]

The main difference is the `Location` header that for some reason gets omitted when accessing the deployed function.

I'll add that this GCP Function is publicly available, and that I've also added `cors` middleware for `express`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi @galah92 ,  could you try to add a return to `res.redirect`.  See this code: `res.redirect("https://studio.asyncapi.com/?" + params);`

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB I cannot because that would cause a type mismatch - `asyncHandler` return value is `Promise<void>`.

Comment: Have you tried to access it on another browser and see if the issue occurs only on chrome. I have tried to reproduce the issue based on your given code above but I was able to deploy it properly without having any issue. Could you please try to include a reproducible code with `cors` configuration, `package.json` and if possible, an api endpoint that we can test to.